# How can I increase the length of the command history in R?

Tags: r

In R, I like to use reverse search (ctrl+r) to redo infrequent but complex commands without a script. Frequently, I will do so many other commands in between that the command history discards the old command. How can I change the default length of the command history?

Comment: What platform?  What interface?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is platform and console specific.  From the help for `?savehistory`:

> There are several history mechanisms available for the different R
>   consoles, which work in similar but not identical ways...
>
> ...
>
> The history mechanism is controlled by two environment variables:
>   R_HISTSIZE controls the number of lines that are saved (default 512),
>   and R_HISTFILE sets the filename used for the loading/saving of
>   history if requested at the beginning/end of a session (but not the
>   default for these functions). There is no limit on the number of lines
>   of history retained during a session, so setting R_HISTSIZE to a large
>   value has no penalty unless a large file is actually generated.

So, in theory, you can read and set `R_HISTSIZE` with:

```
Sys.getenv("R_HISTSIZE")
Sys.setenv(R_HISTSIZE = new_number)
```

But, in practise, this may or may not have any effect.

See also `?Sys.setenv` and `?EnvVar`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the help page for `history()`. This is apparently set by the environment variable R_HISTSIZE so you can set it for the session with `Sys.setenv(R_HISTSIZE = XXX)`. I'm still digging to find where you change this default behavior for all R sessions, but presumably it will be related to `.Startup` or your R profile.

Answer (score 2):

?history

> "There are several history mechanisms available for the different R
>   consoles, which work in similar but not identical ways. "

Furthermore there may even be two history mechanism in the same device. I have .history files saved from the console and the Mac R GUI has its own separate system. You can increase the number of GUI managed history entries in the Preferences panel.

There is an incremental history package:
http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/track/html/track.history.html

Answer (score -1):

In ESS you can set `comint-input-ring-size`:

```
(add-hook 'inferior-ess-mode-hook
          '(lambda()
             (setq comint-input-ring-size 9999999)))
```