# Increase the command window in R

Tags: r

I would like to see the results in console and R_HISTSIZE controls the number of lines that are saved (default 512).

Claim that sys.setenv(R_HISTSIZE=Max) solve the history size is not correct and here is the explanation about sys.setenv.

Description

Sys.setenv sets environment variables (for other processes called from within R or future calls to Sys.getenv from this R process).

Sys.unsetenv removes environment variables.
Usage

```
  Sys.setenv(...)

  Sys.unsetenv(x)
```

Arguments

...
    named arguments with values coercible to a character string.
x
    a character vector, or an object coercible to character.

Details

Non-standard R names must be quoted in Sys.setenv: see the examples. Most platforms (and POSIX) do not allow names containing "=". Windows does, but the facilities provided by R may not handle these correctly so they should be avoided. Most platforms allow setting an environment variable to "", but Windows does not, and there Sys.setenv(FOO = "") unsets FOO.

There may be system-specific limits on the maximum length of the values of individual environment variables or of all environment variables.
Values

A logical vector, with elements being true if (un)setting the corresponding variable succeeded. (For Sys.unsetenv this includes attempting to remove a non-existent variable.)
See Also

Sys.getenv, Startup for ways to set environment variables for the R session.

setwd for the working directory.

The help for ‘environment variables’ lists many of the environment variables used by R.
Examples

```
  print(Sys.setenv(R_TEST = "testit", "A+C" = 123))  # `A+C` could also be used
  Sys.getenv("R_TEST")
  Sys.unsetenv("R_TEST")
  Sys.unsetenv("R_TEST")  # may warn and not succeed
```

Sys.getenv("R_TEST", unset = NA)

Comment: This is not a direct answer, but try use RStudio, where you can view the result variable using the viewer window.

Comment: For a direct answer, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354375/how-can-i-increase-the-length-of-the-command-history-in-r

Comment: The link state the question but they dont have answer.